# Have you used Java 1.8 in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In other words, what are the measurements we should take while migrating an Android app from *Java 1.7* to **Java 1.8**?

Anyone used Java 1.8s powerful features like 
**Lambda, Streams, Java Time API, etc**., in Android applications?

Do you also think the Java 1.8 made Android app will work on all the different devices irrespective of Android OS versions?

Comment: maybe this will help https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am more looking into gathering real life information and developers experience on implementing Java 1.8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have used Java 8 with android studio but Instant Run does not currently work with Jack and will be disabled while using the new toolchain.
Because Jack does not generate intermediate class files when compiling an app
so data binding classes not generated intermediate.

I have used **[retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)** to supports backporting to Java 7, Java 6 and Java 5 runtimes.

Retrolambda lets you run Java 8 code with lambda expressions, method references and try-with-resources statements on Java 7, 6 or 5.